# I have got a stack problem concerning recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int f(int x) {
    int erg;
    if (x >= 1000) {
        erg = x - 3;
    }
    else {
        f(f(x + 5));
    }
 return erg;
}

int main() {

    cout << "Result: " << f(84) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So I get the error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeef3ffff8)

Comment: That questionable recursion aside, `erg` is not initialized when you return it and `x` was smaller than `1000`. What practical problem are you trying to solve with this program?

Comment: @CNNTT It is interesting what is the base case?:)

Comment: With this code I wanted to solve a mathematical question with the help of programming, that I just  recently solved. The question was: There's a function f(x) with f(x) = x - 3 for x >= 1000 and f(x) = f(f(x+5)) for x < 1000. Calculate f(84). Actually there's an easy version to solve this by finding a repeating pattern, what I actually did when I had the question in a test, you obviously also can do the for humans very hard part, so f(84) = f(f(84 +5)) ....., what can be easily calculated with a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining a recursive function but not properly defining an exit condition.
The (inter-related) issues I identify are:

- `erg` is returned uninitialized if the `else` clause is taken.
- you are not doing anything with the result of `f` in the `else` clause. Did you intend to assign it to `erg`?
- Why even have `erg` at this point? You can just return directly from the `if` and `else` clauses.